# Export database schema from Loopback 4 model

Tags: loopbackjs

Is there a way to export database schema from Loopback 4 models.

When you execute `npm run migrate` it can alter the database, but I can't find a way to export the SQL script to generate the database structure.

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 1):

*Hi from the LoopBack team.*

We currently don't support generating the scripts to generate the database structure, though it's a good idea. This GitHub issue: https://github.com/strongloop/loopback-next/issues/4757 tracks the feature request.